# Separate column in dataframe into several other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
                     value
2020-11-20 09:10:28:005 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] increase values: user = "jbohl"
2020-11-20 09:11:10:055 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] redirect: user = "msmith". limit test
2020-11-20 09:10:28:174 INFO <main> {EVENT-upload} [INPUT] new set: id = 12442, user = "msmith"
```

How could i separate column "value" into 6 columns, defined by timestamp and parenthesis? Desired result must look like this:

```
        timestamp           col2      col3          col4               col5              message
2020-11-20 09:10:28:005    DEBUG     <main>      {EVENT-upload}     [Item_create]      increase values: user = "jbohl"
2020-11-20 09:11:10:055    DEBUG     <main>      {EVENT-upload}     [Item_create]      redirect: user = "msmith". limit test
2020-11-20 09:10:28:174    INFO      <main>      {EVENT-upload}     [INPUT]            new set: id = 12442, user = "msmith"
```

**dput:**

```
df <- structure(list(value = c("2020-11-20 09:10:28:005 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] increase values: user = jbohl", "2020-11-20 09:11:10:055 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] redirect: user = msmith. limit test", "2020-11-20 09:10:28:174 INFO <main> {EVENT-upload} [INPUT] new set: id = 12442, user = msmith" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr`'s `extract` and provide a pattern to extract for each column value.

```
tidyr::extract(df, value,
               c('timestamp', paste0('col', 2:5), 'message'), 
               '(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+:\\d+)\\s*([A-Z]+)\\s*(<.*?>)\\s*({.*?})\\s*(\\[.*?\\])\\s*(.*)')

#               timestamp  col2   col3           col4          col5
#1 2020-11-20 09:10:28:005 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create]
#2 2020-11-20 09:11:10:055 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create]
#3 2020-11-20 09:10:28:174  INFO <main> {EVENT-upload}       [INPUT]

#                              message
#1       increase values: user = jbohl
#2 redirect: user = msmith. limit test
#3  new set: id = 12442, user = msmith
```

`timestamp` - extract numbers that follow the pattern `num-num-num num:num:num:num`

`col2` - extract all the following uppercase text

`col3` - extracts value in `<.*>`

`col4` - extracts value in `{.*}`

`col5` - extracts value in `[.*]`

`col6` - all the remaining text.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(value = c("2020-11-20 09:10:28:005 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] increase values: user = jbohl", 
"2020-11-20 09:11:10:055 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] redirect: user = msmith. limit test", 
"2020-11-20 09:10:28:174 INFO <main> {EVENT-upload} [INPUT] new set: id = 12442, user = msmith"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: it gives this error Error in stringi::stri_match_first_regex(x, regex) : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)

Comment: @french_fries Provide data using `dput`. It works for the data shared in my post.

Comment: df <- structure(list(value = c("2020-11-20 09:10:28:005 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] increase values: user = jbohl", 
"2020-11-20 09:11:10:055 DEBUG <main> {EVENT-upload} [Item_create] redirect: user = msmith. limit test", 
"2020-11-20 09:10:28:174 INFO <main> {EVENT-upload} [INPUT] new set: id = 12442, user = msmith"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

Comment: one that you provided

Comment: It works for me with `packageVersion('tidyr') ` `#‘1.1.2’`. What is yours?

Comment: my version is 1.0.0. how could i change it?

Comment: `install.packages('tidyr')`